# Keycloak ask "Invalid Request"

Tags: keycloak, single-sign-on

I installed and configured Keycloak. I configured Clirnt and when I go to the endpoint for authorization, Keycloak responds “We are sorry... Invalid Request” I'm new to SSO. Here are my settings, what am I doing wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIvdo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpf4n.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61pY9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGsxs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oblV.png)

Endpoint that I use for authorization:
`https://ssotest.ru:8443/realms/romashka3/protocol/openid-connect/auth`
I've tried changing settings and tried tips from other questions on Stack Overflow, but I still get the error. I expect a page to appear prompting me to enter my username and password.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.